# OOP web application class design

Tags: oop, class, design-patterns

I'm trying to build a web application using OOP.

In my application i have Courses and Subscribers.
Each Course can have multiple Subscribers (1-N relation).
Now i need to perform some operations on Courses (check some expire dates and perform actions on it's subcribers, send some emails to admins) and, after performing them, perform other operations on each Subscriber (send emails).

I created a Course class and a Subscriber class.
Course class contain course data like title, dates, current status and a group of Subscriber objects (those who partecipate to it).
Subscriber class contains name, last name, subscription status etc.

I have a problem.
My Course class need to be aware of it's Subscribers.

My Subscriber class need to be aware of the Course it belongs to (to exctract data like title, dates...) and aware of how much subscribers are and their status.

How can i redesign my class structure to solve this?
I was thinking about using some kind of observer pattern...

PS. i'm using PHP

Answer (score 0):

No need for a special design pattern, this is a normal bidirectional association. I get from your description that any subscriber only subscribes to one course, otherwise there should be two classes `Student` and `CourseSubscription` instead.

How to simply construct the association in PHP:

```php
class Course
{
    /**
     * @var Subscriber[]
     */
    protected $subscribers = array();

    public function addSubscriber(Subscriber $subscriber)
    {
        $this->subscribers[] = $subscriber;
    }
}

class Subscriber
{
    /**
     * @var Course
     */
    protected $course;

    public function __construct(Course $course, $name, ...)
    {
        $this->course = $course;
        $course->addSubscriber($this);
        $this->name = $name;
        ...
    }
}
```

A subscriber object can only exist with a course, so you pass the course as parameter to the constructor. There the newly created subscriber registers itself for the course.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like an [observer pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx#_self1) till the point you said

> and aware of how much subscribers are and their status.

You need a version of Observer Pattern which expose limited information of its observers.

This point is something like for each subscriber of a course , you need to get all of the subscribers from the course object so you can create a method in Course object which will give you the limited information for each subscriber of the course.

Comment: You are right. That's what is preventing me to use this pattern.

Comment: @Stefano : You should use encapsulation on course object by writing a function which will expose limited information of each object and for rest of the problem you can use Observer Pattern